# Flowers in Arachis hypogea, are they clestogamous or chasmogamous?

Tags: sexual-reproduction, morphology

I have seen the flowers of groundnut, they open and remains open for one day, so they should be chasmogamous, but in my school book, they mentioned it as clestogamous, and I searched for it in wikipedia but it wasn't clear. So how to classify it?